# How to inherit the Odoo default QWeb reports in .py file?

Tags: python, xml, report, odoo, qweb

I want to inherit odoo default qweb report "Picking operation" from stock.picking  in python file.
I know how to inherit default qweb report in xml.
please suggest/guide how to inherit a qweb default report in .py file

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

```html
return self.env.ref('your_module_name.your_menu_id').report_action(self, data=data)
```